# Firebase Storage uses 490MB but I have no buckets?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Firebase Storage is using 490 MB, but no bucket has been initialized.
I am not able to track where this storage com from, but it is quite strange to check that  Firebase is charging 0.10 USD for an empty Storage.

Where can I delete this storage and why firebase is charging for having no buckets?

[image]

Currently I am using Firebase Authentication, Firestore, Realtime Database, Hosting and Functions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Storage bucket fills up gradually as I don't upload anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778920/firebase-storage-bucket-fills-up-gradually-as-i-dont-upload-anything)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every time you deploy to Cloud Functions, it [takes some space in a new storage bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778920/firebase-storage-bucket-fills-up-gradually-as-i-dont-upload-anything).  This is covered in the [documentation FAQ about Cloud Functions billing for node 10](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-pricing).

You can [delete those files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884429/how-to-delete-outdated-firebase-cloud-function-containers-from-gc-storage/63888296#63888296) over time if you want.

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation is to use object lifecycles in the artifacts storage bucket! that way the files deletion is automated.

Follow this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

**(Firebase should be the one responsible for creating this rule!)**